# Get part of the query from a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Suppose i have a text column in some table. I can select a value from this column with

`(SELECT textcolumn from sometable WHERE ....)` and query result will be `'5>3'`.

Now i want to add this result to my other query.

```
UPDATE someothertable SET somecolumn WHERE (SELECT textcolumn from sometable WHERE ....)
```

I want this to act like

```
UPDATE someothertable SET somecolumn WHERE 5>3
```

How can i do this in postgresql?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smth like:

```
do
$$
begin
execute format('UPDATE someothertable 
SET somecolumn 
WHERE %s',(SELECT textcolumn from sometable WHERE ....));
end;
$$
;
```

example:

```
t=# create table ta(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table tb(t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into ta select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into tb select 'i < 9';
INSERT 0 1
t=#     do
    $$
    begin
    execute format('UPDATE ta
    SET i = 2
    WHERE %s',(SELECT t from tb));
    end;
    $$
    ;
DO
t=# select * from ta;
 i
---
 2
(1 row)
```

I don't think this is a good idea though...

Comment: depending on the scenario, there is nothing particularly wrong with Dynamic SQL.  Applications write their own SQL all the time, including pulling data from the database to define that SQL.  The biggest danger comes when any of that process embeds input from a human into the SQL.  "Little Bobby Tables" may come to play.

Comment: Thank you this worked. What if the text column was not in another table but the table we're working on.

`do
$$
begin
execute format('UPDATE sometable 
SET somecolumn 
WHERE %s',textcolumn);
end;
$$
;`.

I tried this, didnt work.

Comment: you would still have to select value from the column `format('UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn WHERE %s',(select textcolumn from sometable))`

Comment: Yes, but i have to select the correct textcolumn(WHERE CLAUSE) for each row. Every row(or featureid) has different textcolumn.